# Filesystem path issue

Tags: php, filesystems, imagick

I am trying to get the `filesystem` path with php `realpath` function because I am using `imagick` class.

I have the following:

```
  $str = $array[0]['FileName'];   //the $str will be /project/employees/info
```

then use

```
  $str = realpath(".".$str);

  var_dump(is_readable($str));  //output false.
```

but it outputs false. I am sure the file path is correct but don't know what went wrong. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you sure apache got read access?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to locate a file relatively to the current file's directory you would use

```
__DIR__ . '/' . $str
```

instead.

This solution is much better, because `.` points to a "current directory" that may be changed to practically anything using `chdir()` in runtime, while `__DIR__` always points to an expected directory.

Comment: note that \_\_DIR\_\_ is php 5.3+ specific. For older versions, you can use dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)